# read a tag within an XML file using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I'm trying to read a tag in an xml file that contains error messages to my javascript file. Problem is I don't know the syntax to grab the error messages via the "errorName" attribute as in my example below.

XML

```
<configuration> 
<msgList>   
<MSG errorName="LETTERSONLY" errorMessage="Letters only please"/> 
<MSG errorName="NUMBERSONLY" errorMessage="Numbers only please"/> 
</msgList> 
<configuration>
```

JAVASCRIPT FILE

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("lettersonly", function (value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^[a-z]+$/i.test(value);
}, "Letters only please");
```

MY CODE

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "errorFile.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function (xml) {
        var xmlError = xml;
    }
});



 jQuery.validator.addMethod("lettersonly", function (value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^[a-z]+$/i.test(value);
    }, $(xmlError).find(?)); --> Stuck
```

Comment: It's exactly the same as if it were a _HTML #document_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what your are looking for,

```
   $(xml).find("[errorName='LETTERSONLY']").attr("errorMessage")
```

http://jsfiddle.net/agentmilindu/6YYDG/